# TortoiseSVN and commit-access-control.cfg

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

In TortoiseSVN, where is the "hooks" directory? Where to place `commit-access-control.cfg` in order to manage control access? Thanks

To make it clearer:
Where does TortoiseSVN install svn on Windows? I've always done it manually in Unix, Tortoise simply created all by itself and I have no idea of where the local repository is. Thanks

Comment: Do I spot some serious misunderstanding here? TortoiseSVN itself gets installed wherever you choose in the wizard (typically `%PROGRAMFILES%\TortoiseSVN`) and repositories are of course created manually via right click.

Comment: in %PROGRAMFILES%\TortoiseSVN I expect to see a "hook" directory just like the one I see when, in unix, I install svn and run "svnadmin create /some/local/repo", but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseSVN is an subversion client software.  The `hooks` folder is present in subversion server.  Read more [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html).

Answer (score 1):

When you issue this command:

```
svnadmin create /some/local/repo
```

... you are creating a **repository** in given path ("/some/local/repo"). The GUI alternative provided by TortoiseSVN is as follows:

1. Open Windows explorer
2. Browse to the folder where you want your repository (e.g. "C:\MyData\")
3. Create an empty folder (e.g. "C:\MyData\ProjectFoo")
4. Right click in the newly created folder and select "TortoiseSVN -> Create repository here"

Thus there's little chance that TortoiseSVN will choose the repository location for you. (And of course this has nothing to do with the location of working copies or TortoiseSVN itself.)

You can find the "hooks" folder inside your repo (e.g. "C:\MyData\ProjectFoo\hooks").

(You appear to be using a [Perl hook script](http://opensource.apple.com/source/subversion/subversion-35/subversion/tools/hook-scripts/commit-access-control.cfg.example). You'll need a working [Perl interpreter](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) to run it.)

Answer (score 0):

The directory should go with each svn respoitory, not with the tortoisesvn program.